# How to import LWC component from ORG to VSCODE?

Tags: visual-studio-code, salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc

I am having some difficulties importing LWC components from org to VSCODE. Is it the right way? Here's what I am following -

1. Created a new **Manifest** project.
2. Connected to my sandbox org (not scratch).
3. Right clicked on Package.xml under Manifest & selected - Retrieve source in Manifest from Org.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, should work. Does your package.xml contain

```
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>LightningComponentBundle</name>
</types>
```

Are you sure you're connecting to right org? If you Ctrl+Shift+P -> Open default org, do you land in the sandbox that contains this component? Any errors when you retrieve? `sfdx` is installed ok?

Do you see your component if you open developer console, query tab, tick the Tooling API checkbox(!) and run `SELECT DeveloperName FROM LightningComponentBundle`?

If all else fails you can query the bodies with Tooling API's `SELECT Id, FilePath, Format, Source FROM LightningComponentResource` but it should "just work"...

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Yes, SFDX is installed and I also checked using your query (tooling API), and its retrieving data. I am new. Maybe data is retrieved and I do not know where to see it. I am checking under LWC folder and its not there. Any suggestions?

Comment: with default project config they should end up in lwc directory, yes. (if your project.json file contains `"path": "force-app"` then they should end up in `force-app\main\default\lwc`). You can try right clicking the directory and hitting "retrieve source from org" too... What happens when you run `sfdx force:mdapi:retrieve -r ./mdapi -k ./manifest/package.xml`? it should download a zip with your source code to "mdapi" folder. any errors?

Comment: Hi Eyescream, What I did was - Refreshed all org data from the left cloud icon and downloaded Apex and Lightning Web Components and it worked. But thank you so much for your assistance!!!!

Comment: weird, I almost never use that icon to be honest, normal deploy / retrieve or push/pull "just works"... Maybe password expired or something. well, glad I could help a bit!